# Double integral of distribution functions with variable in the upper limit

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, probability-distributions

Let $F_x$, $F_y$ be two distribution functions supported on $[0,\infty)$. Is there a way to evaluate the following double integral without assuming $F_x,F_y$ are differentiable and using integration by parts?

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\bigg(\int_{0}^{x}(\alpha-y)\, dF_y(y)\bigg)\, dF_x(x) $$

Comment: That may depend on what $F_x$ and $F_y$ actually are

Comment: Assuming $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables with the corresponding CDFs, this is $$E((\alpha-Y)\mathbf 1_{Y<X}).$$ Other similar reformulations follow.